# update does not provide does not reduce interaction terms

Tags: r

I would like to verify in a loglinear model whether the interaction terms do play a relevant role in my model. For illustration I use the code below that stems from Field (2013): P. 846-848. I do not understand why the "Update" does not work as intended. The formula is taken as-is from the book:

- Data:

  ```
  catdogconttable <- xtabs(~ Animal + Training + Dance  , data=Dataset)
  catdogconttable
  ```
- The fully saturated model:

  ```
  caturated <- loglm(~ Animal * Training * Dance, data = catdogconttable, fit = TRUE)
  summary(caturated)
  ```
- The 3fold-interaction term is omitted

  `threeway <- loglm(~ Animal + Training + Dance + Animal : Training +
   Animal : Dance + Dance:Training , data = catdogconttable, fit = TRUE)`
      `summary(threeway)`
- The 3fold-interaction term is omitted by using `update`

  `threeway1<-update(caturated, .~., -Animal * Training * Dance)`
  `summary(threeway1)`
- Summarising difference in anova show that the result obtained are not
  the same

  `anova(caturated, threeway)`

  `anova(caturated, threeway1)`
- Data available

  [here](http://www.discoveringstatistics.com/r_files/CatsandDogs.dat)
- The question is why does threeway1 not produce the same output as
  threeway?

Comment: have you tried `update(caturated, .~.-Animal:Training:Dance)` ?

Comment: Great - on the provided example it works - however on my own data not...still trying. Txs!